# Mouseover 2 colors with css

Tags: css, css-transitions

Menu item default background-color is white. Mouse hover color is blue

My question is -

If we hold on the mouse hover on the menu item. first need to show blue color later 1 or 2 sec the color should change to some other color yellow.

Is it possible with css Transitions or any idea with CSS?

Comment: Difficult without Javascript and will probably work in very few browsers.

Comment: @specialscope This is feasible via CSS transitions; see the answer of afshin for example. You could also use CSS animations and define keyframes, when to display which color…

Answer (score 3):

Try this maybe help

HTML

```
<div class="test"><div></div></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
​.test{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0ff;  
   -webkit-transition:background-color 1s ease-in; 
    -moz-transition:background-color 1s ease-in; 
    -o-transition:background-color 1s ease-in; 
    transition:background-color 1s ease-in; 
}
.test div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 3s ease-in;
     -moz-transition:background-color 3s ease-in;
     -o-transition:background-color 3s ease-in;
     transition:background-color 3s ease-in;
}
.test:hover{
   background-color:#f00;
}

.test div:hover{
   background-color:green;
}
```

​[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKXua/)

Comment: is this transition compulsory for my requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with CSS3 animations (works in modern browsers). Here's an example which changes the color of the button from grey to blue and then yellow.

Hope that helps!

Demo - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjz69/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.button:hover {
     -webkit-animation: color 1.0s forwards;
        -moz-animation: color 1.0s forwards;
          -o-animation: color 1.0s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color {
      0%   { background-color: #0000ff; }
      50%  { background-color: #0000ff; }
      100% { background-color: #ffff00; }
}

@-moz-keyframes color {
      0%   { background-color: #0000ff; }
      50%  { background-color: #0000ff; }
      100% { background-color: #ffff00; }
}

@-o-keyframes color {
      0%   { background-color: #0000ff; }
      50%  { background-color: #0000ff; }
      100% { background-color: #ffff00; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for.
http://www.acuras.co.uk/articles/53-javascript--css-flashing-text--how-to-do-it--why-not-to-do-it

Honestly, I have no idea why you need such a link, it will just make your website seem like it was made by a complete beginner, because it is very distracting. There are much nicer animations and plugins out there, especially if you use jQuery. Check this out for inspiration: http://bestofjquery.com/

Comment: Actully i am thinking a logic for tablet. Mouse hover effect doesnt work in tablet. if you have the style for mouse over when we tap on any of menu item, the hover color is highlighted and even i remove the finger it showing the hover color. So in the case, im thinking... . That is when i tap on the menu item the hover will be active. If css is availabe for two colors in hover, default color i will apply for secondary color of hover. You got my point.  There are so may menu items in my web site. we need to delivary as early as possible. Thats y i am try to fix with CSS